# subdomain route loading first route

Tags: php, laravel

I have cleared my routes list and cache however I am still getting the webpage for my first route why?

**Route List:**

```
--+
| {place1}.domain.co.nz     | GET|HEAD  | / App\Http\Controllers\controller@place1                             | web           |
| {place2}.domain.co.nz | GET|HEAD  | / | App\Http\Controllers\controller@place2
```

**Route:**

```
Route::group(['domain' => '{place1}.domain.co.nz'], function (){
    Route::get('', 'controller@place1');
});

Route::group(['domain' => '{place2}.domain.co.nz'], function (){
    Route::get('', 'controller@place2');
});
```

Comment: I would suggest to delete the brackets { }, if you don't, every subdomain request will go to first route, with the subdomain value contained in a `$place1` variable. For example, if you hit place2.domain.net, the first route will be used and `$place1` will be equal to `'place2'`

Answer (score 0):

In your case your need hardcoded second subdomain. For example

```
Route::group(['domain' => 'place2.domain.co.nz'], function (){
    Route::get('', 'controller@place2');
});

Route::group(['domain' => '{place1}.domain.co.nz'], function (){
    Route::get('', 'controller@place1');
});
```

So any subdomains except `place2` will go to the first route.

Comment: And I would say to put second domain first, if not, even second domain will hit first route.

Comment: @El_Matella I think it's not required. I believe it will works correct in my examle.